# Parsing Complex JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am new to PHP and not very clear how to parse JSON with PHP. This is the JSON i am getting from a third party

```
{ "data": 
  { "current_condition": 
   [ 
      {"cloudcover": "0", "humidity": "13", "observation_time": "05:47 AM", "precipMM": "0.0", 
      "pressure": "1016", "temp_C": "20", "temp_F": "69", 
      "visibility": "10", "weatherCode": "113",  
      "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ],  
      "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], 
     " winddir16Point": "SW", "winddirDegree": "218", "windspeedKmph": "12", "windspeedMiles": "7" 
     } 
   ],
   "request": [ 
            {"query": "Lat 32.12 and Lon 76.53", "type": "LatLon" } 
      ],  
   "weather": [ 
          {
            "date": "2012-11-04", "precipMM": "0.0", "tempMaxC": "20", "tempMaxF": "69", "tempMinC": "1", "tempMinF": "34", 
            "weatherCode": "113",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ],  
            "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], 
            "winddir16Point": "SW", "winddirDegree": "218", "winddirection": "SW", "windspeedKmph": "12", "windspeedMiles": "8" 
           }, 
          {
           "date": "2012-11-05", "precipMM": "0.0", "tempMaxC": "20", "tempMaxF": "67", "tempMinC": "4", "tempMinF": "39", 
           "weatherCode": "113", "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ], 
           "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], 
           "winddir16Point": "SSW", "winddirDegree": "210", "winddirection": "SSW", "windspeedKmph": "12", "windspeedMiles": "7" 
           } 
          ] 
        }
     }
```

I am getting this weather information as JSON data which includes following information

1. Current information
2. Weather information for next 2 days

I do not want all information but only specific one like

```
current_condition
       temp_C
       temp_F
       weatherDesc
```

Than i want some data from the weather information provides for next 2 days

1. date
2. tempMaxC
3. tempMinC
4. weatherIconUrl
5. windspeedKmph

i tried this code in PHP

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($weather, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

which seems to give me the JSON decoded data in the array format but i got confused in how to fetch those specific values from the PHP data. I can iterate over the Data

```
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
    }

    } else {
       // echo "$key\n";
    }
```

but not sure how to fetch values as described above.Any help or pointer for resources will really be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then process the resulting object?

Example: http://codepad.org/ciw3ogAu

I used `ob_get_content()` because I don't want to mess up with the escape sequences, but the focus is on this line:

```
$result = json_decode($my_json_string);
```

It's not difficult to obtain information. For example if you want the current temperature in Celsius:

```
echo $result->data->current_condition[0]->temp_C;
```

You can get an array of the future two days (http://codepad.org/bhOcd3eT):

```
$weatherarray = $result->data->weather; // An array with two elements
```

---

You use `$result->xxx` instead of `$result["xxx"]` because [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will create objects for objects. You can change it to be arrays by calling `json_decode($my_json_string, true)`, then you access members using the following way:

```
echo $result["data"]["current_condition"][0]["temp_C"];
```

Comment: my first attempt was with the one you mentioned, but some how i again got struck how to fetch that particular information

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi check my new answer

Comment: +1 you made my confusion go clear, i was all struck in the proper use of PHP syntax :).Will try and see how it goes for me

Comment: Thanks, that is just more than perfect :)

Comment: Example Links are 404

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode your json object, but you don't need to iterate it. Just access the information you want :

```
$decoded = json_decode($weather);
$date = $data->current_condition->data->weather->date;
$tempMaxC = $data->current_condition->data->weather->tempMaxC;
$tempMinC = $data->current_condition->data->weather->tempMinC;
$weatherUrl = $data->current_condition->data->weather->weatherIconUrl;
$windspeedKmph = $data->current_condition->data->weather->windspeedKmph;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this approach to access your data :

```
$data = json_decode($weather);
```

And then your can easily get what you want this way :

```
print_r($data->data->current_condition);
```

or in a loop...

Answer (score -1):

```
$decode=json_decode($file);    
echo $decode->data->current_condition[0]->temp_C; 
echo $decode->data->current_condition[0]->temp_F; 
echo $decode->data->current_condition[0]->weatherDesc[0]->value;   

foreach ($decode->data->weather as $data) {
  echo $data->date;
  echo $data->tempMaxC;
  echo $data->tempMinC;   
  echo $data->weatherIconUrl;
  echo $data->windspeedKmph;  
}
```